# Case classes, persistence and Play forms

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Over the course of creating a basic application using Play and Anorm I've encountered a problem when dealing with entities not yet saved to database. The form obviously doesn't have a field for ID so I can't create a mapping using the case class `apply` method. I ended up creating two classes - one for persisted entities and one for not yet persisted and the code looks something like this

```
case class EphemeralUser(email: String)

case class PersistentUser(id: Long, email: String)

val userForm = Form(mapping("email" -> text))(EphemeralUser.apply)(EphemeralUser.unapply)

def create(user: EphemeralUser): PersistentUser = { /* Save with Anorm */ }
```

Is there a more elegant way to deal with it using a single `case class User(id: Option[Long], email: String)` ? Or even better, some way to remove code repetition cause I kinda like the fact that persisted and ephemeral users are different types.

Comment: What's wrong with two different types? They are different. One is saved and one isn't. When you have an instance of the type with an ID, you know it is saved. When you have an instance of a saved type, you know it has an ID.

Comment: @drstevens I like two type approach more because of additional type-safety but there's a lot of boilerplate. There's a trait that `def`s all the fields and common behavior and two constructors for respective case classes. Though at the moment I don't need an edit form, it seems there will be some repetition there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary to require two types. Making the `id` an `Option[Long]` should be enough. To test if a model has been persisted would just require you to check that `user.id.isDefined`.

Your `Form` could then use `ignored` to still take advantage of `apply` and `unapply`:

```
case class User(id: Option[Long], email: String)

val userForm = Form {
    mapping(
        "id" -> ignored[Option[Long]](None),
        "email" -> email
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right thing to do, at least, it's what I do at work; my case classes tend to define persistence IDs as type `Option[Long]`. This is assuming, of course, that your persistence ID needs to be passed around your application in the data model.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about it is that it's slightly less convenient to access an `Option[Long]` id, but I'm willing to put up with that more often than not.